# Translate SSL command line curl to PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to translate a commandline **Curl** to **PHP Curl**.
This is the commandline:

```
curl -v -k --key "filekey.key" --cert "filecert.cer" --capath "path to site root" "complete link"
```

Thanks to all
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

Why not check PHP documentation for full options list? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php Including options:

- CURLOPT_CAINFO
- CURLOPT_CAPATH
- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Answer (score 0):

In my case is "secure-direct.rhapsody.com" (which is also the root of $linkToExecute) . –